# How to write chemical formulas from Python variables?

Tags: mhchem, pythontex

I would like to store/read chemical names from some Python code, and pretty-print them using the `mhchem` package. However, the following code doesn't work. I expect it has something to do with when the `\py` macro is expanded, but none of the things I can think to try with `\edef` and `\expandafter` seem to work. How can I make the chemical equation from a string print like the first form?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
    \ce{C8H18}

    \begin{pycode}
        chem_form = 'C8H18'
    \end{pycode}
    \py{chem_form}

    \ce{\py{chem_form}}

    \expandafter\ce{\py{chem_form}}

    \edef\chemform{\py{chem_form}}
    \edef\cee{\chemform}
    \cee
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\py` macro is not expandable, but you can work around this as shown in section 8 of the manual, where an example about `\SI` is explained (pages 55–56).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{pycode}
chem_form = 'C8H18'
def ce(formula):
    return '\\ce{' + str(formula) + '}'
\end{pycode}

\newcommand\pyce[1]{\py{'\\ce{' + str(#1) + '}'}}

\begin{document}

\ce{C8H18}

\py{ce(chem_form)}

\pyce{chem_form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's very easy... I have done very much the same thing to get siunitx to work, including writing a whole function to process the output from the pint Python package... Thank you!